# Split text if its content exceeds numbers line limit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextview, line

Conditions:

- UITextView that can contains X lines as maximum:disable scroll. (For example; max lines = 8)
- A huge text content. (For example; 25 lines)
- Language is English. (Word-wrap is compulsory)

How can I split text if its content exceeds numbers line limit?
I want to split text into array. Following the condition, the text should be split to 4 elements.

**Update:** 
Actually what I want to achieve is like when I have a long text and I have the fix text container size (eg. UITextView) which cannot display all content, then there is a next button to reset container and display the left content. I thought that split string would help but it seems a wrong choice. I am trying what Matt's suggestion and hope the problem will be solved.

Comment: Do you intent for users to edit the text? If not, a bunch of `UILabel` nested inside a `UICollectionView` may work better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is not a good one. Instead of splitting the text into four arrays of text, it would be better to take advantage of Text Kit and let the layout manager split the text into four text containers (one NSLayoutManager, four NSTextContainers).

This could even be combined with your current use of a text view for display purposes: the four text containers could belong to four text views, and now you have four noneditable nonscrollable text views that *automatically* distribute the text between them, and you can just switch among those text views.

Here's an example with just two text views:

[image]

That's two UITextView objects governed by *one* NSLayoutManager, so that as the text becomes too long for the first text view it *automatically* flows into the second text view.

If you *really* wanted to, I suppose you could do what I just said and *then* use the layout manager to ask what it did, i.e. to read backwards from the line fragments to the glyphs to the character ranges and find out *how* it split the text into four text containers; but this seems silly when you consider that the problem is already solved before you even start to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and sorry for my poor description. Actually what I want to achieve is like when I have a long text and I have the fix text container size (eg. UITextView) which cannot display all content, then there is a next button to reset container and display the left content. I am not familiar with NSLayoutManager but I will try and see what I can do. As you said, my goal is not right.

Comment: My answer is exactly how you do that.

Comment: Thank you Matt, following your guide, finally I did it.